# MS-Access: hotkey to display a message box

Tags: ms-access, vba

I need particular users the ability to lock a record on a form, but I don't need anything too serious such as setting different security settings.

Idea: I would like to be able to have a certain keydown combination (ex: ctrl+alt+M) to open a message box. (I'm trying to avoid making a small form because all I need returned is either yes, no, or cancel)

I have been looking around, but I'm not sure where to start with this one... Your feedback is always appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered [`AutoKeys macro`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access/HA102391111033.aspx)?

Perhaps you wish to make it [`form specific`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/130856)?

Comment: I did, but I don't know how to get the functionality I want. (I want to make it more complicated than just "F2") I've posted my code as an answer.

Comment: Have you looked at the form's Key Preview property? If you open the form's property sheet and put the cursor in the property (it's on the Events tab) and hit F1 you'll get an explanation of how to use it.